# How can i achieve something like a vertical ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-viewpager, touch

It may not be a great question but i am asking for some help.
I am not a pro so please if anything is unclear post a comment and i will try to explain.
I have an activity where i have a full screen ImageView where over it i have a couple of texts and an other overlayed imageview, i want when i swipe up to send the whole view upwards and to show from below a simillar view but with different image,
i don't need to detect swipe gesture, i need the view to track my finger's Y (vertical value) , and as i have my images into an array , how can i create the same view for each image ? I am not using adapter and as i know adapters works only with gridview and listviews, please if someone knows help me !

Comment: @durbnpoisn i have tried to use listview with adapter and make the adapter's layout nearly as a fullscreen but the problem is that i can scroll how much i want and the image won't auto fit into the screen , it can shows only from half of screen , i need to auto-fit just like viewpager but vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use RecyclerView I think it can do what you want